# Google Earth Engine: set Feature to FeatureCollection, but not a whole Array

Tags: arrays, properties, set, google-earth-engine

I try to add a new Feature to the large Feature Collection, but with a function set() its override the whole list to each feature. But my purpose is to add each value from the array to the corresponding FeatureCollection. Can anybody help me?

```
    var table = ee.FeatureCollection(ft:.....blablabla);

    **//Create an Array from the property DN in the FeatureCollection:**
        var propert = table.limit(100).aggregate_array('DN');
    *// Values less than 1 will be set to 1, larger than 1== 0:* 
        var limit =  ee.Array(propert).lt(1);
        print(limit);
     //Function, that add the list! of features (limit) to new property (Class) in the FeatureCollection ("table"). 
        var addFeature = function(ar) {
          return ar.set({Class: limit});
     //Map throw the Featurecollection table
        var areaAdded = table.limit(100).map(addArea);
        };
```

So, if you can see, my code add the whole Array [limit] to each property in the FeatureCollection, not a first Value from the Array to the first property and so on... 
Could anybody help me? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a smallish number of features, you can convert the feature collection to a list, convert the array to a list, `zip()` them together, map a function over the lists to set the property.  Toy example:

```
var features = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(30.01, 59.80, 30.59, 60.15), {name: 'Voronoi'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781), {name: 'Thiessen'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(6.4806, 50.8012), {name: 'Dirichlet'})
];

var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection(features);

var array = ee.Array([2, 3, 5]);

var lists = fromList.toList(fromList.size()).zip(array.toList());

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(lists.map(function(l) {
  return ee.Feature(ee.List(l).get(0)).set('foo', ee.List(l).get(1));
}));
print(features);
```